# Thevenin’s theorem, find the voltage across R4

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, thevenin

I was try to solve this problem many time but the final answer is always wrong and not like the one in the book "Vth=11.7 V"
i have a midterm exam this week so i hope i can know how to solve it early :(.
Thevenin’s theorem, find the voltage across R4.

[image]

Comment: *Hint:* If you simplify the circuit first (R5//R2) and this value  is in series with R1 it should all drop out

Comment: What you're aiming at is a circuit with the 50V battery in series with R3 (4k7) with **all the other resistors reduced to a single value**, so yes, simplify R4//R6 as **one** of the steps towards this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try redrawing the circuit with the voltage source driving all of the resistors. You'll find that it becomes a simple divider between the 4.7K and the equivalent of the others, which comes out to about 1.449K. I came up with 11.78V across R4.

Answer (score 0):

Start by finding the voltage at the top ends of R3, R4, etc, considering the negative terminal of the battery as the 0 V reference.

This is easier than it may appear, since multiple resistors can be combined into single resistors.

Hint: Note that R2 and R5 are in parallel.